# Elasticsearch index got corrupted

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am getting the following logs from the elasticsearch box:

```
org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: [myindex][2] Preexisting corrupted index [corrupted_5Y_pGXmYQOG5PGlZURWqxw] caused by: CorruptIndexException[checksum failed (hardware problem?) : expected=9cf1207c actual=4eda74a3 (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(NIOFSIndexInput(path="/mnt/vol1/myindex/nodes/0/myindex/index/2/index/_3758.fdt")))]
org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: checksum failed (hardware problem?) : expected=9cf1207c actual=4eda74a3 (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(NIOFSIndexInput(path="/mnt/vol1/my/indexnodes/0/indices/myindex/2/index/_3758.fdt")))
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checkFooter(CodecUtil.java:211)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.CodecUtil.checksumEntireFile(CodecUtil.java:268)
    at org.apache.lucene.codecs.compressing.CompressingStoredFieldsReader.checkIntegrity(CompressingStoredFieldsReader.java:535)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.checkIntegrity(SegmentReader.java:624)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentMerger.<init>(SegmentMerger.java:61)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.mergeMiddle(IndexWriter.java:4158)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.merge(IndexWriter.java:3768)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:405)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TrackingConcurrentMergeScheduler.doMerge(TrackingConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:106)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler$MergeThread.run(ConcurrentMergeScheduler.java:482)

    at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store.failIfCorrupted(Store.java:452)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.store.Store.failIfCorrupted(Store.java:433)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.applyInitializingShard(IndicesClusterStateService.java:725)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.applyNewOrUpdatedShards(IndicesClusterStateService.java:578)
    at org.elasticsearch.indices.cluster.IndicesClusterStateService.clusterChanged(IndicesClusterStateService.java:182)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:431)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Can anyone tell how to fix the issue?
Also, what are the best practices to reduce such issue?

I had similar issue previously for which I have to delete the replica box content and reassign it to the cluster. I then that got fixed for some days, but it reappeared again today.

**EDIT**:
The problem was that all the elasticsearch box were sharing the same hard disk and thus when multiple replica tries to write on the same disk location, the disk crashed. It was done by mistake and now I create  individual disks for each replica.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what ES version you are. Before *1.3.2* you may try to [set the indices recovery compression to `false`](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-1-3-2-released).

I experienced this exception on 1.3.2. The cause was a full disk. Some shards recovered after a good while, some not. Reindexing helped.